# OpenCL SDK Linux Download for INTEL GPU

Tags: linux, opencl, intel

Is there an Intel OpenCL SDK Download for linux?  I was looking for an opencl sdk for my intel i5 (HD 4000 graphics) and it seems that they only have it for windows.

Answer (score 13):

Intel has recently started an opensource project [Beignet](http://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/Beignet/) which is Linux specific. They use `Mesa` infrastructure and `LLVM/Clang` for `OpenCL` implementation. Although not all the features are implemented yet, its being developed in a [fast phase](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ1NTU). Currently it works on `Ivy-bridge` and `Haswell` GPUs.

**Edit:**
as of 2015, September OpenCL 1.2 support is quite complete.

Also, supported targets are listed in [wiki](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/):

> **Supported Targets**
>
> - 3rd Generation Intel Core Processors
> - Intel “Bay Trail” platforms with Intel HD Graphics
> - 4th Generation Intel Core Processors "Haswell"
> - 5th Generation Intel Core Processors "Broadwell".

Comment: Have you used Beignet? And if so what do you think of it? How does it compare to Intel's closed source OpenCL drivers?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't for the GPU. And according to this thread (http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/402118) Intel won't tell us if or when they will release such a thing.

The Intel OpenCL SDK only works with CPUs and the Xeon Phi right now. And for CPU, you may want to try out the AMD SDK even for Intel CPUs. I'm running a benchmark right now and is seems to be faster. Also has better support of free tools (CodeXL).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, that amd sdk works for intel cpus (in fact it works with beignet too).

Comment: Intel has since released https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-media-server-studio which includes Linux OpenCL support but costs $499. I'd use Beignet instead, they accept patch requests and have a public mailing list for help.